# why icons are not showing?

Tags: html, css

```
 <div class="bottom">
    <input type="range" name="range" id="myprogressbar" min="0" max="100">
    <div class="icons">
        <!-- fontawsome icons -->
       <i class="fas fa-2x fa-step-backward"></i>
       <i class="far fa-3x fa-play-circle"></i>
       <i class="fas fa-2x fa-step-circle"></i>
    </div>
   </div>
```

```
 <div class="bottom">
    <input type="range" name="range" id="myprogressbar" min="0" max="100">
    <div class="icons">
        <!-- fontawsome icons -->
       <i class="fas fa-2x fa-step-backward"></i>
       <i class="far fa-3x fa-play-circle"></i>
       <i class="fas fa-2x fa-step-circle"></i>
    </div>
   </div>
```

After adding this in html I didn't get my icons on web page.
I can't see icons on web page, while i have to add link of font awesome web in css or html file

Comment: Where is your link for the font awesome library? What link are you using? Double posting your code makes it not readable more then posting it once (quite the opposite).

Answer (score 2):

Check your link for the font awesome library.
Also, the `fa-step-circle` icon doesnt exist, i think you want `fa-step-forward` instead

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="bottom">
    <input type="range" name="range" id="myprogressbar" min="0" max="100">
    <div class="icons">
        <!-- fontawsome icons -->
       <i class="fas fa-2x fa-step-backward"></i>
       <i class="far fa-3x fa-play-circle"></i>
       <i class="fas fa-2x fa-step-forward"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should wait what the OP actually did. The question misses the necessary details. If this question is caused by an incorrect link it would be a reason for closure and removal (not reproducible or caused by typos). An answer (especially with upvotes)  makes the removal harder.